# How to programmatically access a publishing site's current navigation settings

Tags: 2013, navigation, publishing

I can see the current navigation items using the (SP2013) Site Settings Navigation page.

Problem is, I'd like to access this set of items programmatically, and in particular, to discover which ones are hidden.

However, using the Navigation api, I see considerably more items than the UI shows, and the IsHidden attribute is uniformly False, even for the items the UI says are hidden.

The Publishing Navigation api doesn't seem to have any properties that expose this list.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using Managed Metadata Navigation or Standard Navigation?

Comment: Standard Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Using `publishingPage.IncludeInCurrentNavigation` you can check if a `publishingPage` is hidden.
To get a `publishingPage` instance use `GetPublishingPage(url)`.